# What's causing this site to redirect to my localhost?

Tags: redirection, hosts-file

[[x-post SO]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18934982/opening-yoast-com-opens-up-my-localhost-dev-server)

[yoast.com](http://yoast.com) is redirected to [my localhost server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vX9mq.png).

[image: web page]
[image: cmd ping]

I've only mapped localhost to `gomlm.gopagoda.com` [in my HOSTS file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fd97t.png), so that I can work on my localhost version without changing the original hosting address (`gomlm.gopagoda.com`) in the database.

I have nothing set up that should redirect [yoast.com](http://yoast.com) to my localhost server.

Moreover.. since I have Wordpress's multisite feature enabled, the redirect is even more …'funny' --
it actually redirects to `http://gomlm.gopagoda.com/wp-signup.php?new=`**`yoast.com`** (as seen above)

I can't think of any reason why this is happening.

---

#### Upon using a [VPN](http://www.vpnbook.com/#openvpn),

it [times out.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvPfi.png)
My local server (`localhost`/`127.0.0.1`/`gomlm.gopagoda.com`) works fine though.

---

#### Upon using a [web-proxy](http://hidemyass.com), [yoast.com](http://yoast.com) opens up!

And I've found out that it's not just yoast, but some sites linked on yoast also don't open normally when I try.

[image]

As seen, it is also misbehaving in a similar way.
`gomlm.gowp..com` is my localhost server, (see above images), how that is even showing up in there (in ghostry) is beyond me!

---

#### Upon renaming my localhost webserver's main directory (so as to make it inaccessible to everything), I get this:

[image: HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error]

Comment: Please don't cross post on multiple SE sites.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your DNS cache? Run `ipconfig /flushdns` from an administrative command prompt.

Comment: @druciferre just did. didn't help.

Comment: Wow!! I just found out that it was my Android device (which I was tethering) [had an entry for yoast.com](http://imgur.com/5CeT4ka.png).

Comment: It definitely seems like a DNS issue to me. What do you have set as your DNS server on the PC? Do you have it set to your router?

Comment: @laggingreflex, glad you got it worked out!